# all-the-icons - weird icons after update

Tags: terminal-emacs

I recently updated my emacs packages, after this, all-the-icons change its icons. Now, that's how they look

[image]

Why a .md file icon is a wheater icon?

How I can go back to my previous icons?

Comment: Could you please share your config?

Comment: I'm seeing icons similar to yours after update - perhaps you should file a report on [github](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a problem with all-the-icons.el and not all-the-icons-dired. An issue [has been filed](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/issues/99).

Comment: @cactus if this is the solution, (and it seems the issue has an explanation on how to fix the problem) please mark it as such to prevent the community bot from bumping it